# Timber get list of categories and their childs

Tags: wordpress, timber

I'm using timber in a project, i have googled without success about my need : i want to loop categories and their respective childs :

```
// inside my shortcode
...
$context['categories'] = get_categories(['hide_empty'=>false, 'parent'=> 20]);
return \Timber::compile( MY_DIR_PATH . '/views/preferences.twig', $context );

// inside the view (preferences.twig)
{% for category in categories  %}
    
     // Here how i get children of this current category ?
     {% for child in function('get_categories',{'hide_empty': 'false', 'parent': category.term_id }) %}
     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

From code above, i can output with success each category parent, but on the second loop i don't know how to list childrens based ont the parent category : category.term_id

I searched from timber documentation but no way, someone has an advice please ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In previuos projects I constructed the nested category parent/child data in my php and then passes the constructed data array to timber, see example below:

```
function get_sorted_categories() {

    // Get categories
    $cat_args   = array(
        'hide_empty'=>false, 
        'parent'=> 20
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

    if ( $categories ) {

        // Store category heirarchy
        $cat_data = array();

        // build data array.
        foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {

            $cat_data[ $cat->term_id ] = array(
                'name'     => $cat->cat_name,
                'snippet'  => $cat->cat_description,
                'link'     => get_category_link( $cat->term_id ),
                'children' => array(),
            );

            // Child categories
            $cat_args_child   = array(
                'hide_empty'=>false, 
                'parent'=> $cat->term_id
            );
            $child_categories = get_categories( $cat_args_child );
            if ( $child_categories ) {

                foreach ( $child_categories as $child_cat ) {
                    $cat_data[ $cat->term_id ]['children'][]  = array(
                        'name'     => $child_cat->cat_name,
                        'snippet'  => $child_cat->cat_description,
                        'link'     => get_category_link( $child_cat->term_id ),
                    );
                }

            }
                
        }
        return $cat_data;
    }

    return false

}
```